# Set datefirst permanently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'd like to change permanently the value of DATEFIRST (*which is used for functions like **DATEPART***)

If I do this : `SET DATEFIRST 1` the value stay during the execution **but** it return to the default value - 7 here - after the execution

I already had the problem, I know that it's related to the country of the login but I forgot which table & which property I had to change.

Comment: Use ALTER LOGIN to set the language of the login(s) as suggested by @MartinSmith in comments

Comment: But I don't see any other comments ...

Comment: (The comment is on my deleted answer)

Comment: I did, as it wasn't going to work in Sql Server 2008, can you not see the deleted answers?

Comment: No, maybe it requires more privileges

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise that: this was the comment  - "'allow updates'- This option is still present in the sp_configure stored procedure, although its functionality is unavailable in SQL Server. The setting has no effect. Starting with SQL Server 2005, direct updates to the system tables are not supported." - from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179262.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say this took some research on my part.  Take a look at the following query. You will notice the datefirst field. I would imagine there are all kinds of permission implications that go along with changing language settings at this level.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sys.syslanguages
```

I don't have a server I can test this on at the moment but I would imagine through a set statement you could set the datefirst column to whatever you wanted it to be.

TEST TEST TEST as this will have huge implications across more than problem you are trying to solve.

[Interesting Resource # 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[Interesting Resource # 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/62ba79c6-172e-4360-86e2-79bfb356a0f2/)

[Interesting Resource # 3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/b533994a-f343-46bb-a29e-0c3663138397/)

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the default language of a sql login or windows user authenticated on SQL Server using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio or executing the below sample t-sql script :

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [login] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [you_language]
GO
```

[The script was taken from this site](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-set-datefirst-scope-permanent-for-sql-server-database.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late to the party, but here's a way to "hack" it, regardless of the datefirst value, set either to the server, db, login or session and parametrizable (WOW, never used this word before) by the first day you actual want it to be :

```
declare 
/*
 Let's say for a regular, boring day of Monday
, regarldess of the datefirst value, I want it to return Monday as 1 (first day of week)
*/
@ForDate datetime = '20170320',
-- you can play with any value here
@SetDateFirstValue int = 5

--this is only for testing
set datefirst @SetDateFirstValue;

select 
  datepart(dw,@ForDate) as ActualReturnedDayOfWeek
, datepart(dw,dateadd(dd, @@DATEFIRST - 1,@ForDate)) As IWantItThisWay
```

P.S. : Perhaps the only situations you'll ever need this, is in a function  or constraint (computed columns maybe) where `SET` operations are not allowed. If `SET` is allowed, SET it as you need it and forget about it.